# How to extract some piece of word from a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, startswith, ends-with

I have the following string in python:

```
datastring = """
Animals {
    idAnimal
    nameAnimal
    animalko5854hg[name="Jazz"]
    animal6ljkjh[name="Pinky"]
    animal595s422d1252g55[name="Steven"]
    animalko5854hg[name="David"]
}
"""

print(type(datastring))#->str
```

My string is data than a read before from a file text, now I have that data in `datastring`.
In `datastring` always in the fourth line, the data is showed in the next way: `animalidAnimal[name="nameAnimal"`

So I would like to code a function that takes as a parameter a string like above, and return the part of `idAnimal` of the first line that starts in the following way: `animalidAnimal[name="nameAnimal"`
So for example in the first string my expected output would be:

```
ko5854hg
```

Other example:

```
datastring = """
Animals {
    idAnimal
    nameAnimal
    animal456jlk165ut[name="Dalty"]
    animal6ljkj[name="Moon"]

}
```

Expected output:

```
456jlk165ut
```

Last example:

```
datastring = """
Animals {
    idAnimal
    nameAnimal
    animalk45lil69lhfr5942lk[name="Jazz"]
    animal6ljkjh[name="Pinky"]
    animal595s422d1252g55[name="Steven"]
    animalko5854hg[name="David"]
    animalko5854hg[name="Oty"]
    animalko5854hg[name="Dan"]
}
```

Expected output:

```
k45lil69lhfr5942lk
```

I don´t want to be considered as a lazy person, but I don´t really know how to start coding that, I read about `startswith` and `endswith` functions, but those only return `True/False` values.

Thanks.

Comment: You just want animal id of the First animal? Or all animals

Comment: Just the first animal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start the match with `{` and use a capture group for the animalId:

```
{[^{}]*?\banimal(\w+)\[name="[^\s"*]*"]
```

The pattern matches:

- `{` Match a `{` char
- `[^{}]*?` Match any character except { and } as few as possible
- `\banimal` Match animal with a leading word boundary
- `(\w+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ word characters
- `\[name="[^\s"*]*"]` Match the `[name="...."]

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x2pJA7/1)

Example code

```
import re

pattern = r"{[^{}]*?\banimal(\w+)\[name=\"[^\s\"*]*\"]"

s = ("Animals {\n"
            "    idAnimal\n"
            "    nameAnimal\n"
            "    animal456jlk165ut[name=\"Dalty\"]\n"
            "    animal6ljkj[name=\"Moon\"]\n\n"
            "}")

m = re.search(pattern, s)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Output

```
456jlk165ut
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using regexes?
Using `re.find_all(r"(?<=animal)(.*?)(?=\[)",datastring)` would show up the list of IDs so if you want the first occurence you can get the ID with the 0 index, good luck

Thanks for notifying me about that, here's a simplier way thanks again for letting me know:

```
for line in datastring.splitlines():
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith("animal"):
        id = line.replace("animal","").split("]")[0]
```

I think KillerRebooted's answer is more effective but as I said this is more simple

Comment: This cannot work as the OP's data contains leading spaces so the startswith() test will never be True

Comment: Oh yes my bad I'll add the strip() real quick

Answer (score 0):

You should probably allow for the line starting with 'animal' not necessarily being the fourth line. This might be more robust:

```
datastring = """
Animals {
    idAnimal
    nameAnimal
    animalko5854hg[name="Jazz"]
    animal6ljkjh[name="Pinky"]
    animal595s422d1252g55[name="Steven"]
    animalko5854hg[name="David"]
}
"""
ANIMAL = 'animal'

def get_animal_id(ds):
    for line in map(str.lstrip, ds.splitlines()):
        if line.startswith(ANIMAL):
            return line[len(ANIMAL):line.index('[')]

print(get_animal_id(datastring))
```

**Output:**

```
ko5854hg
```

**Note:**

If the first line observed starting with 'animal' does not contain '[' this will fail with ValueError

You could also do this using a regular expression thus:

```
import re

print(re.search(r'(?<=animal)(.*?)(?=\[)', datastring).group(1))
```